# Windows - Set a Printer's Processor Programatically via batch or regedit

Tags: windows, batch, printer, control-panel

is there a way to automate the change of a printer's processor via batch file or a registry key \ policy ?

[image: change Print Processor manually]

Answer (score 0):

Found it, for future searchers:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Printers]

"Print Processor"="winprint"

Comment: Hello polisha989, you seem to have created two accounts. [See the help center for merging accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts). Welcome to superuser!